# Laravel Backpack: CRUD for one-many relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I have a model called Report that has one-many relationship to another model called ReportAttachments.

In my ReportCrudController class, I have a the following field to add or manage attachments.

```
$this->crud->addField([   // Browse multiple
    'name' => 'attachments',
    'label' => 'Image Attachments',
    'type' => 'browse_multiple',
    'multiple' => true, // enable/disable the multiple selection functionality
    'mime_types' => ['image'], // visible mime prefixes; ex. ['image'] or ['application/pdf']
    'model' => 'App\Models\ReportAttachment',
    'attribute' => 'id',
    'entity' => 'attachments'
]);
```

However, I cant seem to make it work as I get this error during edit:

> "Property [attachments] does not exist on this collection instance."

**Also, when creating a new report, empty insert query is generated for the attachments which throws an exception:**

> "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'file' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `report_attachments` () values ())"

This is the code for Report Model:

```
class Report extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait;


    protected $table = 'reports';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'slug', 'description', 'impression'];

    protected $casts = [
        'attachments' => 'array',
    ];


    public function attachments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ReportAttachment');
    }

}
```

Code for Attachment Model

```
class ReportAttachment extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'report_attachments';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['file', 'title', 'file_type'];
    public $timestamps = false;


    public function report()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Report');
    }
}
```

Am I missing something or doing something wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Update: 
*added table definition and updated namespace for model ReportAttachment*

```
CREATE TABLE `reports` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `impression` enum('0','1','2') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `reports_name_unique` (`name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `reports_slug_unique` (`slug`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=37 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

report_attachments table:

```
CREATE TABLE `report_attachments` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `file` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `file_type` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `report_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `report_attachments_report_id_foreign` (`report_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `report_attachments_report_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`report_id`) REFERENCES `reports` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: In yor DB the "report_attachement" table contains reports_id from table "reports"?

Comment: Quick note: one of your models has a namespace of `App\Models` (`App\Models\Report`), the other doesn't: `App\ReportAttachment`

Comment: @kerbholz Updated the namespace ReportAttachment and as suspected, I am still experiencing the same issues.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski updated the question with table definition. report_attachments has report_id foreign key.